# Icing texture for Cake

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

[image]

Hi all,

I'm trying to create a texture for the cake icing pictured above. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

For the color it's just the following:

[image]

Here I set the "Subsurface Radius" to: 0.8, 0.8, 0. The subsurface color is just the base color but with maximum saturation. The subsurface value is set to 0.2 here, but in your case it might have to be lower, since the sphere I rendered is 2m wide and if you're using an accurate scale, then your icing shouldn't be that big.

For the bump I used a noise texture to drive the "normal" input:

[image]

Once again, the scale and strength might have to be different in your case, but you get the idea. Other than that, all the values from the principled BSDF are the same as default.